# Giving Access For Virtual Machines Created by me to others - Azure

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, azure-active-directory, azure-cloud-services

I'm creating a Virtual Machine in Azure. Now How to make others to access that Virtual Machine. Im looking for some thing like giving permission for a set of users based on role. The same is possible in AWS through IAM. Now how to do the same in Azure.
   Kindly Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent of `IAM` in Azure is [`Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/). Using RBAC you can assign fine-grained permissions on your resources in Azure to users in your organization.

You can start with some of the [`Built In Roles`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/) - `Reader`, `Contributor`, `Owner` or `Virtual Machine Contributor`. If you want even more fine-grained permissions, you can create your own [`Custom Roles`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-custom-roles/).